instgaram ,facebook app browser does read responsive codes on some smartphones
I build project with Next.js . Some responsive codes does not read through instagram app browser. For example line heights, heigth, i tried wih rem but not effected also wrote      -webkit-line-height: 18px !important;
-webkit-letter-spacing: -0.015em !important; but not effected. how can solve this issue ?
